Replace NULL with NIL when using JSON or Hash
I have the following JSON and I'm trying to replace null with nil because ruby can't compile it.
I get the following error undefined local variable or method "null" for main:Object (NameError).
AlarmDescription and Unit is null.
How can I resolve this? I tried replace and gsub but couldn't replace null with nil.
jsondata = {
  AlarmName: "Zabbix PY 5XX - By Stage QA",
  AlarmDescription: null,
  AWSAccountId: "123456",
  NewStateValue: "ALARM",
  NewStateReason:
    "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (06/11/21 12:16:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
  StateChangeTime: "2021-11-06T12:17:43.811+0000",
  Region: "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)",
  AlarmArn: "arn:aws:cloudwatch:ap-south-1:123456:alarm:Zabbix PY 5XX - By Stage QA",
  OldStateValue: "INSUFFICIENT_DATA",
  Trigger: {
    MetricName: "5XXError",
    Namespace: "AWS/ApiGateway",
    StatisticType: "Statistic",
    Statistic: "MINIMUM",
    Unit: null,
    Dimensions: [
      { value: "zabbixPy-API", name: "ApiName" },
      { value: "qa", name: "Stage" },
    ],
    Period: 60,
    EvaluationPeriods: 1,
    ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
    Threshold: 1,
    TreatMissingData: "- TreatMissingData: missing",
    EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile: "",
  },
}

puts jsondata

Error:
Output:

HelloWorld.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object (NameError)

  AlarmDescription: null,


Your jsondata isnt a JSON, its a ruby hash, so it has to be nil because its ruby code not json.

I'm getting this data from AWS. How can I modify to change null to nil with hash?

I guess this is the result of an api call to AWS is it ? Add the request and how you parse the response.

I'm working with raw hash. Can you tell me how to convert null to nil with raw data (my jsondata variable)?

I see, but you canot throw invalid code like this. Either you set a json file that you parse with the ruby code, or, you manually change null to nil ... Where are you getting this hash ? This is not a valid ruby hash.

Where does that data structure come from? This isn't JSON and AWS doesn't return Ruby hashes. Most likely, you're already doing some parsing on your side. And that's what needs to get fixed. Having null in there is merely a symptom, not the root cause.

Me again, i've been trying some things. Tell me if this resolves your problem.

texte = %q(
{
  AlarmName: "Zabbix PY 5XX - By Stage QA",
  AlarmDescription: null,
  AWSAccountId: "123456",
  NewStateValue: "ALARM",
  NewStateReason:
    "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [1.0 (06/11/21 12:16:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
  StateChangeTime: "2021-11-06T12:17:43.811+0000",
  Region: "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)",
  AlarmArn: "arn:aws:cloudwatch:ap-south-1:123456:alarm:Zabbix PY 5XX - By Stage QA",
  OldStateValue: "INSUFFICIENT_DATA",
  Trigger: {
    MetricName: "5XXError",
    Namespace: "AWS/ApiGateway",
    StatisticType: "Statistic",
    Statistic: "MINIMUM",
    Unit: null,
    Dimensions: [
      { value: "zabbixPy-API", name: "ApiName" },
      { value: "qa", name: "Stage" }
    ],
    Period: 60,
    EvaluationPeriods: 1,
    ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
    Threshold: 1,
    TreatMissingData: "- TreatMissingData: missing",
    EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile: ""
  }
}
)

texte = texte.gsub('null', 'nil')
ruby_hash = eval(texte)

puts ruby_hash.inspect
puts "----"
puts ruby_hash[:Trigger][:EvaluationPeriods]


Yea that worked. Thanks

require 'json' looked promising but unfortunately, you didn't use the JSON library at all afterwards. Regarding eval – you shouldn't use it to parse anything out of your control (like user input or 3rd party API responses). It's best to just avoid that method.

You're right about the json, i've edited the answer.
And for the eval, i know, but he is throwing raw hashes, i suppose by hand himself, without any user interactions it seams. Do you have an other solution ?

You mean the hash is hard-coded? If so, the OP could just replace null with nil using their text editor / IDE.

Thats what i understood from the 6th comment, and i say the same on the 7th. Then i just answer the question, cause he didn't give me the request or his parsing :')
